# React 16.7 TypeError: (0 , _react.useState) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Error:

```
  TypeError: (0 , _react.useState) is not a function
```

My current react versions:

```
   "react": "^16.7",
   "react-dom": "^16.7",
```

src/App.js:

```
  import {memo, useState} from 'react'
  export default memo(() => {
     useState(false)
     return 'OK'
  })
```

src/App.test.js:

```
   import React from 'react'
   import App from './App'
   import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
   it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON()
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
   })
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause is that the react V16.7 does not have hooks

Resolution is to downgrade to

```
   npm i react@next react-dom@next
```

which as of 2018/12/20 is 16.7.0-alpha.2:

```
    yarn add react@next react-dom@next
```

then lose the test renderer:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
 import App from './App'
 it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div)
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div)
 })
```

This is what package.json should have:

```
  "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
```

Comment: By "downgrade" do you mean "upgrade"?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the mistake was in the imports. My IDE imported the useState hook from import 'react/cjs/react.development' and it dosen't work on production.